# Significant framerate drop when using Cocos2D in multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I have an iOS app that uses `UIKit` for the most part, bot for two `UIViewController`s, I use `Cocos2D`.

I set up `Cocos2D` like so:

```
@implementation CocosScreen1 {
    @private

    CCDirectorIOS* director;    
    CCScene* scene;
    CCLayer* comicLayer;

    UINavigationBar* navBar;
    UIView* bottomOptionsBar;
    CCGLView *glView;
}


-(void) setupCocos2d; {

    glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:self.view.bounds pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565                                   depthFormat:0 preserveBackbuffer:NO sharegroup:nil multiSampling:NO numberOfSamples:0];    
    director = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    director.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60]; // set FPS at 60
    [director setView:glView];  // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setDelegate:self]; // for rotation and other messages

    [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];   // 2D projection

    if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO]; 
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];

    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    CCScene* bottomScene = [CCScene node];
    [director pushScene:bottomScene];

    scene = [CCScene node];
    comicLayer = [[AgComicLayer alloc] initWithOptionsView:optionsParentView withReaderScreenReference:self];

    UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)];
    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];        
}
```

And then the two screens have this called before they appear:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
    [self.view insertSubview:director.view atIndex:0];  

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];    
    [director pushScene:scene];
}
```

And then the two screens have this called when they disappear:

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    [director popScene];
}
```

**What happens is that one of the screens works perfectly fine. However, the other `Cocos2D` scene suffers an insane amount of framerate drop from 60 to 4. And it fails to start animations performed via the `runAction` method.**

I need to solve the framerate issue and have the second scene resume correctly and play animation. What is wrong with my implementation? Are there best practices for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resume the director. You're pausing it, but never resume. Pause means reducing the fps to 4. Since the director is a singleton pause/resume affects both views.